# Crop video in iOS see weird green line around video

Tags: ios, iphone, video, camera

Hey everyone I am cropping a video taken from the camera on iPhone and then cropping it an playing it back like this. When i do it however I get a weird green line around the bottom and right side of the video? Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. Here is how I am cropping.

```
- (UIImageOrientation)getVideoOrientationFromAsset:(AVAsset *)asset
{
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    CGAffineTransform txf = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

    if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty)
        return UIImageOrientationLeft; //return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0)
        return UIImageOrientationRight; //return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width)
        return UIImageOrientationDown; //return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    else
        return UIImageOrientationUp;  //return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}


- (AVAssetExportSession*)applyCropToVideoWithAsset:(AVAsset*)asset AtRect:(CGRect)cropRect OnTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)cropTimeRange ExportToUrl:(NSURL*)outputUrl ExistingExportSession:(AVAssetExportSession*)exporter WithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError* error, NSURL* videoUrl))completion
{

//    NSLog(@"CALLED");
    //create an avassetrack with our asset
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

//create a video composition and preset some settings
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

CGFloat cropOffX = cropRect.origin.x;
CGFloat cropOffY = cropRect.origin.y;
CGFloat cropWidth = cropRect.size.width;
CGFloat cropHeight = cropRect.size.height;
//    NSLog(@"width: %f - height: %f - x: %f - y: %f", cropWidth, cropHeight, cropOffX, cropOffY);

videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(cropWidth, cropHeight);

//create a video instruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = cropTimeRange;

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* transformer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:clipVideoTrack];

UIImageOrientation videoOrientation = [self getVideoOrientationFromAsset:asset];

CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (videoOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height - cropOffX, 0 - cropOffY );
        t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, M_PI_2 );
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0 - cropOffX, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - cropOffY ); // not fixed width is the real height in upside down
        t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, - M_PI_2 );
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0 - cropOffX, 0 - cropOffY );
        t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, 0 );
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - cropOffX, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height - cropOffY );
        t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, M_PI  );
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"no supported orientation has been found in this video");
        break;
}

CGAffineTransform finalTransform = t2;
[transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

//add the transformer layer instructions, then add to video composition
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:transformer];
videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

//Remove any prevouis videos at that path
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]  removeItemAtURL:outputUrl error:nil];

if (!exporter){
    exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality] ;
}
// assign all instruction for the video processing (in this case the transformation for cropping the video
exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
if (outputUrl){
    exporter.outputURL = outputUrl;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch ([exporter status]) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"crop Export failed: %@", [[exporter error] localizedDescription]);
                if (completion){
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        completion(NO,[exporter error],nil);
                    });
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"crop Export canceled");
                if (completion){
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        completion(NO,nil,nil);
                    });
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (completion){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completion(YES,nil,outputUrl);
            });
        }

    }];
}

return exporter;
}
```

And then I play and call the crop like this.

```
AVAsset *assest = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.videoURL];


NSString * documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *exportPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/croppedvideo.mp4"];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];


AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:assest presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];


[self applyCropToVideoWithAsset:assest AtRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 57.5 - 5, self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 140, 115, 85) OnTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(assest.duration.value, 1))
                    ExportToUrl:exportUrl ExistingExportSession:exporter WithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSURL *videoUrl) {
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoUrl];

AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(125, 365, 115, 115);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
[view.layer addSublayer:layer];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[player play];
```

If you want to test this, the code just need to be copied and pasted and then set a video, and you will see what I am talking about.

Thanks for taking the time to help me I know it is a fair bit of code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are width requirements for either the iOS encoders or the video format itself. Try making your width even or divisible by 4.

I wasn't aware of there being a similar requirement for height, but that could be worth a try too.

I've never found it documented, but requiring evenness makes a certain amount of sense as h.264 uses a 4:2:0 yuv colour space, where the UV component is half the size (in both dimensions) of the Y channel, which has the overall dimensions of the video. If those dimensions weren't even, the UV dimensions wouldn't be integral.

p.s. the hint in these cases is the mysterious green colour. I think it corresponds to 0, 0, 0 in YUV.

Comment: it had to be done for both width and height, but wow thats so weird

Comment: Cool. Was it a multiple of 2 or 4?

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @Rhythmic saved my day.

In my app, I need square video as per screen width size. So for iPhone 5 this comes 320 pixels, and for iPhone 6 this becomes 375 pixels.

So I came across same green line issue for iPhone 6 size resolution. Because its screen size width is 375 pixels. And not divisible by 2 or 4.

To come out of this we made these changes:

```
 AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainInstruction.timeRange = range;
    
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = VideoFrameDuration; //Constants
    MainCompositionInst.renderScale = VideoRenderScale; //Constants
        
    if ((int)SCREEN_WIDTH % 2 == 0)
        MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH);
    else // This does the trick
        MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH+1, SCREEN_WIDTH+1);
```

Just add one more pixel to it so it becomes divisible by 2 or 4.

Comment: smart explanation, i've seen @Rhythmic answer, it is actually a nice answer. but when the matter of short time. you won the toss. ;)  so +1 for you.