# Video played with AVPlayer has grey line to top and sides on iPhone 6S Plus

Tags: ios, avplayer

This seems to be a device specific bug on only **iPhone 6S Plus**.

Steps:

1. Download [AVPlayer demo sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)
2. Adjust `AVPlayerDemoPlaybackView.xib` so that `MPlayback View` has margins around it
3. Make content view color white

1px grey lines will appear at the top and sides.

Anyone knows how to workaround this?

I have tried to put an opaque view that obscure the top, yet the line will still appear ABOVE the opaque view!

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @KapilChoubisa Nope I believe there is no solution. I could see the same lines even on Gmail onboarding!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Lets get this answered

Comment: Started a bounty. To give some more background on the error. MY use case is we have an animated logo that we want to animate on loop. We have a white background, and use a white background on the image as well. (Same color white). It appears perfect on all devices EXCEPT the 6Plus, 6SPlus and 7Plus and even then only on physical devices, not the simulator. It appears to be a 1px grey border ,but I suspect it is actually that the white of the 6Plus is more perfect than the white of the video, thus causing the issue.

Comment: Is this reproducible on iPhone 6S Plus Simulator?

Comment: @shallowThought Nope not on simulator

Comment: I was only able to replicate on the device.

Answer (score 18):

Setting the `AVPlayerLayer`'s [`shouldRasterize`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410905-shouldrasterize) property to `true` makes the borders disappear.

Comment: And also you should set .layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale, to keep same video quality

Comment: @Augard but this brings grey lines back.

Comment: Using shouldRasterize with layer.rasterizationScale worked for me, thank you @TomGlider and @Augard!

Answer (score 4):

Not only `shouldRasterize`, you need to set `rasterizationScale` as well.

```
playerLayer.shouldRasterize = true
playerLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: great tip! `playerLayer.rasterizationScale` is needed to maintain video quality across devices

Comment: great! it works fine

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be that since your use case is an animated loop to ditch the AVPlayer and use a UIImageView.

`UIImage` has [`animatedImage(with:duration:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624149-animatedimage) where you can input an array of images and animate them how you like.

I think this would solve your problem. In my experience AVPlayer has been a little wonky with iOS 10. I think that since you are only seeing this problem on the 6s+ and 7s+ is proof that it has some issues.

If you are absolutely committed to figuring out the AVPlayer, first submit a bug report to Apple. Then maybe try adding a UIImageView behind your AVPlayer that has the image set to a blank frame from your video. This is kind of a hacky solution, but it might work. Additionally, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505631/crop-video-in-ios-see-weird-green-line-around-video) stack overflow post. It might shed some light on the issues you are having with the AVPlayer.

Best of luck.

Comment: Great ideas. Both are good solutions to the problem! Will try and report back results. I think the key to the problem is that UIColor.white for some reason is a different pure white than the pure white on the imported images... thus you see a contrast line on the Plus devices. (Pure white seems to be the same on all the other devices)

Answer (score 1):

I tried Nate4436271's answer and it worked for me, I mean, had the same issue and got rid of the gray lines, but setting the shouldRasterize property to true, made my video lose image quality. So, I set the videoGravity of my playerLayer to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill and I got rid of the lines, while maintaining image quality :)

Here is what I did:

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

AspectFill was within my needs and solved the problem. You may wish to evaluate whether other options are better for what you need, like AspectFit or Resize.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this: The for me easiest way to solve this is to just position a 1px/2px high view on top of your video layer and give it the color you want it to be - this way you can "hide" the grey border by simply putting something on top of it. Needless to say this is super hacky, but it works. You might have to do some calculation on the actual positioning based on your `videoGravity` property.